# Find a real number a < 1 so that the events are independent.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence, exponential-distribution

Let $X \sim \mathrm{Exp}(2)$. Find a real number $a < 1$ so that the events
$\{X \in [0, 1]\}$ and $\{X \in [a, 2]\}$ are independent.

I'm stuck on this one. So far I found $P(X \in [a, 2])$ and $P(X \in [0, 1])$. Where do I go from here?

Comment: To be independent, the probability of one event has to not matter on whether the other event is true or not.  So the probability of being in $[a,2]$ has to equal the probability of being in $[a,1]$ given that it is in $[0,1]$.

Comment: What is the definition of the independence of two events?

Comment: Show us what you've done so far.

Comment: Note that the intersection of these two events is just $\{X\in[a, 1]\}$. Now calculate this probability and find $a$ such that it matches the product of the probabilities you already found.

Answer (score 2):

Let $E=\{X\in[0,1]\}$ and $F=\{X\in[a,2]\}$. For $E$ and $F$ to be independent, we must have
$$
\mathbb P(E\cap F) = \mathbb P(E)\mathbb P(F).
$$
Now,
$$
\mathbb P(E) = \int_0^1 2e^{-2t}\ \mathsf dt = 1-e^{-2}
$$
and
$$
\mathbb P(F) = \int_a^2 2e^{-2t}\ \mathsf dt = e^{-2a}-e^{-4}.
$$
The product is then given by 
$$
\mathbb P(E)\mathbb P(F) = \left(1-e^{-2}\right)\left(e^{-2a}-e^{-4}\right).\tag1
$$
Since this quantity is never zero, $E\cap F$ must be nonempty. For $a\in(0,1)$ we have $\mathbb E\cap F = \{X\in[a,1]\}$, and so
$$
\mathbb P(E\cap F) = \int_a^1 2e^{-2t} = e^{-2a} - e^{-2}.\tag2
$$
Equating $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have
$$
\left(1-e^{-2}\right)\left(e^{-2a}-e^{-4}\right) = e^{-2a} - e^{-2},
$$
and hence
$$
a = 2-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(1-e^2+e^4\right)\approx 0.06223.
$$